# Long equation does not page break

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I have a series of equations steps, about 20 lines or so. I would like to have it automatically decide page break when necessary, but it resists and always tries to stay in a whole page, rendering the previous page a lot of while space.

I tried `\allowdisplaybreaks` and `\displaybreak`, but doesn't seem to work.

```
{\allowdisplaybreaks\begin{equation}\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\begin{split}\allowdisplaybreaks
\alpha\beta\gamma&=abc\\
=def\\
=ghi\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}}
```

Comment: Have you consider accepting the answer?

Answer (score 14):

From page 6 of the [amsmath manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

> Certain equation environments wrap their contents in an unbreakable
>   box, with the consequence that neither `\displaybreak` nor
>   `\allowdisplaybreaks` will have any effect on them. These include `split`,
>   `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat`.

Put differently, use an `align` environment -- along with something like `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Personally I always try to break up long sequences of equations with a few words or sentences.

Comment: This is a nice workaround but not really a solution. I think its a bug in LaTeX.

Comment: It is not a bug in `LaTeX`. It is the behaviour described by the package manual.

Comment: @IanThompson: In fairness, documenting an undesirable behaviour doesn't make it desirable by decree.  This being fixed is not beyond debate in my opinion. :)

Comment: You could justifiably argue that it is a limitation of the `amsmath` package, but it is neither a bug nor part of `LaTeX` itself.

Comment: @IanThompson -- the decision to disallow page breaking with `split` was based on long-standing publishing practice.  you may disagree with it, but i believe i can find published documentation (from the metal type era) supporting it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton --- I wasn't criticising the design. Other users argued that it is a bug; I pointed out that it isn't.

Comment: @IanThompson -- didn't mean to criticize you; just trying to provide a little background.  (a lot of people seem to feel that decisions like this are arbitrary and/or "undesirable".  *that* was the target of my comment.)