# align* but show one equation number at the end

Tags: equations, numbering, page-breaking, amsmath, align

I am using `align*`, but I still need an equation number. I know one solution is to use `align` and add `\nonumber` to all lines but the last. Is there a 'lazy' way to do it?

I searched a little and found similar ones suggesting use `split`: 
[Show equation number only once in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment)

Unfortunately, due to the page break issue I have, I need to use `align`, because `split` won't auto page break, as described in [Long equation does not page break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42720/long-equation-does-not-page-break).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Use `\tag`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a &=b \\
  &=c \numberthis \label{eqn}
\end{align*}
Equation \eqref{eqn} shows that $a=c$.
\begin{equation}
d = e
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

See page 3 of the [amsmath package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for details.

Comment: Why didn't you use `\stepcounter` or `\refstepcounter` instead of `\addtocounter`?

Comment: @PSTikZ --- `\refstepcounter` isn't needed, as the `\ref` value is set correctly already. `\stepcounter` is probably the best choice, to take care of subsidiary counters. I don't think I gave much thought to this when I composed the answer.

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me, thank you. I have a followup question though. How can I make the number on the same line than the last line of the euqation provided that the last line is longer normal `align` would allow (it does fit in `align*` though)

Comment: @magu_ Please post a new question with an example showing exactly what you want. I think I understand your question, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, other users (who may have better solutions than me) will see the new question, whereas they are unlikely to see new comments here.

Comment: This solution has a problem when combined with the `cleveref` package: The sorting of `\numberthis`-references does not work properly. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224047/cleveref-does-not-sort-self-defined-tags) for further detail. If anyone knows a solution fixing this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a bit surprised to learn that this is the best one can do. For me, \numberthis and then \label{...} is still a lot of typing. Maybe I should use another \newcommand... that bundles the two. (I am extremely lazy and sometimes forgets to type \numberthis in \align*, which leads to errors).

Comment: For completeness, when I change addtocounter to stepcounter I also have to delete the "{1}" in the command.

Answer (score 63):

Another option is to use `align`, and then use `\nonumber`, as mentioned in http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &=b \nonumber \\
b &=c
\label{eq:test}
\end{align}
Equation \eqref{eq:test} shows that $a=c$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The user seems to want to use an `align*` environment, though. Your approach would involve a lot of `\nonumber`, if the `align` contains a lot of lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This answer, while technically correct, is already mentioned in the second sentence of the question; the asker is looking for a different solution.

Comment: I must have misread the question. I did not see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 21):

Here are minimal working examples that I use. This is what I have 
as a header

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}           
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
```

Two equations each with separate equation numbers and separate reference labels

```
\begin{align}
        \dot{a} &  =2\alpha(t)\eta\label{classicalmotion1}\\
        \dot{\eta} &  =-2\gamma(t)a\label{classicalmotion2}%
\end{align}%
```

Two equations with a single equation number and a single reference label

```
\begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}[b]
        \dot{A} &  =2i\alpha(t)B\\
        \dot{B} &  =2i\gamma(t)A
        \end{aligned}
\label{eqn2.qo}
\end{equation}
```

I am guessing you know how to do the one without equation numbers.

Comment: thanks! somewhat surprisingly putting the \label(eqn2.qo} before \begin{aligned} changed the position of the eqn number in my case...

Comment: @Xi'an -- putting the `\label` before the `align` might change the position of the equation number, but it will also give an incorrect value with `\eqref`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn}
\begin{align*}
a &=b \\
  &=c \tag{\ref{eqn}} 
\end{align*}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Try having two equations like that, you will see that this code doesn't work.

Comment: @user156344: tried and it works as well (of course your need to change the equation labels).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stupid "lazy" solution:

```
\newcommand{\NNN}{\nonumber\\}
% . . .
\begin{align}
a & = b \NNN
  & = c \NNN
  & = d \\
v & = w \NNN
  & = x \NNN
  & = y \NNN
  & = z
\end{align}
```

I wish `align*` be extended to allow for a `\number` command. That would be a mirror image, sort of, of `align`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new environment based on `align*` that adds the equation number at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignb}{b}{%
  \begin{align*}
  \refstepcounter{equation} #1 \tag{\theequation}
  \end{align*}
}{}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

Check the reference: \eqref{test}

\begin{alignb}
a &= b \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= d \\
  &= e \\
  &= f \label{test}
\end{alignb}

\end{document}
```

I used `a6paper` so the picture is smaller, in order to show that page breaks are honored.

[image]