# How to add a line break in math mode but number the whole as one formula?

Tags: math-mode, equations, line-breaking

I am trying to get the following formula on two lines like this:

```
\begin{equation}
 W \in \mathbf{M}_N \rightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}\\
(w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} \mapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}
\text{with} \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
w_{ij} = w_{ij} \quad \text{for} \; 1\leq i,j\leq N \\
w_{i,N+1} = w_{i,k}\\
w_{N+1,i} = w_{k,i}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

I've read about `align` and `align*` environments, however I want something in between.

What I want is this thing to be numbered (and to be able to reference it) but only once, as one formula, and what the `align` environment does is number both lines seperatly (or not at all in `align*`)

What can I do to make this happen?

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is similar to @Bernard's, it seems to me the list of cases belong with the second line alone. The following numbers only the second line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  W \in \mathbf{M}_N & \rightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}
  \notag\\[-8pt]
  (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} & \mapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}
  \text{ with }
    \begin{cases}
      w_{ij} = w_{ij} &\text{for } 1\leq i,j\leq N \\
      w_{i,N+1} = w_{i,k}\\
      w_{N+1,i} = w_{k,i}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I've also adjusted some of the horizontal spacing of text (`\text{ with }`) and the vertical spacing between the lines. I've also left out the `text{for}` as it is implied anyway (and this leaves room for the equation number). But the key point is that align allows one to turn off numbering of select lines with `\notag`.

Another approach is to use `aligned` inside `equation`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  W \in \mathbf{M}_N & \rightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}\\[-8pt]
  (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} & \mapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}
  \text{ with }
    \begin{cases}
      w_{ij} = w_{ij} & 1\leq i,j\leq N \\
      w_{i,N+1} = w_{i,k}\\
      w_{N+1,i} = w_{k,i}
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The lines of `aligned` are not numbered, but the equation as a whole is.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `cases` environment. See section 3.7 of the [amsmath package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Here I have split your equation in two so that it does not spill over the right margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 W \in \mathbf{M}_N \rightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}
(w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} \mapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
w_{ij} = w_{ij} & \text{for } \; 1\leq i,j\leq N \\
w_{i,N+1} = w_{i,k} &\\
w_{N+1,i} = w_{k,i} &
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

[image: cases]

Comment: I guess that the OP wants only one number.

Comment: @Sigur Using `equation*` in one of the two places will handle that.

Comment: Right. I was thinking about only one number vertical aligned. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that you specified you want to place the entire expression on two lines. However, I think the following form, which extends over five lines and uses a `split` environment inside an `equation` environment, may have some merit:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 W \in \mathbf{M}_N &\rightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}\\
(w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} &\mapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}\\[1ex]
\text{with}\qquad
w_{i,j}   &= w_{i,j} \text{ for $1\leq i,j\leq N$} \\
w_{i,N+1} &= w_{i,k}\\
w_{N+1,i} &= w_{k,i}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `alignat`, `aligned` and `cases`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
 & \begin{aligned}
  W \in \mathbf{M}_N & \longrightarrow W' \in \mathbf{M}_{N+1}\\[4pt]
  (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N} & \longmapsto (w_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq N+1}
\end{aligned}
  & \enspace \text{with}&
\ \begin{cases}
w_{ij} = w_{ij} \enspace \text{for} \; 1\leq i,j\leq N \\
w_{i,N+1} = w_{i,k}\\
w_{N+1,i} = w_{k,i}
\end{cases}
\end{alignat}

    \end{document}
```

[image]