# splitting middle equation of 2 rows

Tags: equations

I have a very long equation which does not fit on the page and I am wondering if anybody can help me to align it properly.

```
\begin{align*}
&(q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\ 
&=q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}+q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8} \\
&=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{align*}
```

It would be nice if the helpful if the last line was numbered like other equations but not essential.

Answer (score 7):

You could just put part of the equation on the subsequent line and add a `\quad` or `\qquad` leading space.  However, my preference is to use `alignat` to get the binary operators aligned, which I think makes it easier to read:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `alignat` solution required the use of `\mathclap` so that those equations did not effect the alignment. This is available in [the `mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) (which already includes `amsmath`).
- As per  barbara beeton's suggestion, I added a `{}` for the last `=` within the `\mathclap`. This make the `=` a binary operator and yields proper alignment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Use \verb|\quad|
\begin{align*}
&(q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\ 
&\quad=q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\
&\quad+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8} \\
&\quad=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{align*}
or use \verb|\qquad|
\begin{align*}
&(q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\ 
&\quad=q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\
&\qquad+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8} \\
&\quad=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{align*}
Alternatively, you could use \verb|alignat*|
\begin{alignat*}{4}
&\mathrlap{(q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8)} \\ 
&\quad=q^{1+2} &&+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\
&\quad&&+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8} \\
&\quad\mathrlap{{}=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignat is what I think I'm looking for. What is the code for alignat? I can't seem to find how to use it properly. Thanks.

Comment: @user50291: Opps, forgot to update the code. The `alignat` code is there now.

Comment: @Manuel: I am not familiar with `\MoveEqLeft`. Perhaps you should add an answer using that?

Comment: the last `=` sign isn't aligned.  i think you can fix it by preceding it with `{}`.

Comment: The first of these solutions, and @Thruston 's eblow, use the alignment to clarify the semantics of the expansion. Some such solution is best for your readers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that takes a different approach to demonstrating the multiplication of the indices, by lining them up to make the totals more obvious.  Personally I like doing this sort of thing using Knuth's `halign` structure, as I think it's simpler, but if you are just starting out you may prefer to use more standard LaTeX facilities instead.  So there are two versions here.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% so we can put the equation number at the bottom
\newcommand\tagmehere{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}
First using plain TeX facilities, embedded in LaTeX.
\begin{equation}
\vbox{\openup3pt\halign{\quad#&&${}#$\hfil\cr
    \omit $\left(q^1 +q^3 +q^5 +q^7\right)\left(q^2 +q^4 +q^6 +q^8\right)$\hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\smallskip}
     & =q^{1+2} & +q^{1+4} & +q^{1+6} & +q^{1+8} \cr
     &          & +q^{3+2} & +q^{3+4} & +q^{3+6} & +q^{3+8}  \cr
     &          &          & +q^{5+2} & +q^{5+4} & +q^{5+6}  & +q^{5+8}  \cr
     &          &          &          & +q^{7+2} & +q^{7+4}  & +q^{7+6}  & +q^{7+8} \cr
    \noalign{\smallskip}
     & =q^3     & +2q^5   & +3q^7   & +4q^9   & +3q^{11} & +2q^{13} & +q^{15}  \cr
}}
\end{equation}

And now using an \texttt{alignat} environment
\begin{alignat*}{8}
    \mathrlap{\left(q^1 +q^3 +q^5 +q^7\right)\left(q^2 +q^4 +q^6 +q^8\right)}\\[\smallskipamount]
    & \quad && =q^{1+2} && +q^{1+4} && +q^{1+6} && +q^{1+8} \\
    &       &&          && +q^{3+2} && +q^{3+4} && +q^{3+6} && +q^{3+8} \\
    &       &&          &&          && +q^{5+2} && +q^{5+4} && +q^{5+6} && +q^{5+8} \\
    &       &&          &&          &&          && +q^{7+2} && +q^{7+4} && +q^{7+6} && +q^{7+8}\\[\smallskipamount]
    &       && =q^3     && +2q^5    && +3q^7    && +4q^9    && +3q^{11} && +2q^{13} && +q^{15}\tagmehere
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

### Notes

1. The OP wanted the equation number at the end.  In the plain TeX version this happens naturally since I've wrapped the alignment in a `vbox` (which has lots of height but not much depth) and the equation number gets lined up with the baseline.  If you wanted the number centred, you would use a `vcenter` instead of the `vbox` so that the baseline was in the middle.  In the `alignat` version we have to put the tag in by hand to get it at the bottom, but I use a little macro to update the equation counter neatly (borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end)).  I considered using an `alignedat` inside an equation - this puts the equation number amidships, but that's not really what was wanted.
2. In the plain solution the `\openup3pt` adds some extra space between the lines so that they look a bit better with all the superscripts. I use `\noalign{\smallskip}` to insert some extra space where we want it.  In the LaTex version we don't the extra `openup` space as this is done automagically, and we put the extra line spaces in just by using the optional argument to the end of line marker.
3. The `alignat` requires all those double `&&`s because it is assuming that I have a bunch of equations and it therefore makes alternate columns align left and right.  No such nuisance in the `halign`.

Comment: this does make some things apparent that i don't see in other approaches, but it would be nice to have a latex solution.  use `mathtools` (loads `amsmath`).  try embedding an `alignedat` structure in an `equation` to get a single number; use `&&` to get the proper left alignment.  you'll have to choose a (possibly) arbitrary alignment point in the first line and use `\mathrlap` to keep from fouling up the other lines.  i won't have tex access for another week, but i'd like to see this answer provided, so i'm making a suggestion instead.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'll have a go.  Just occasionally, the plain TeX alignment facilities are easier to use, I find.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with @PeterGrill 's answer, using the `\MoveEqLeft` command provided by `mathtools`. Still, you can't get rid of one last `\quad` or `\qquad`, but I think the `\MoveEqLeft` is useful here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft (q^1 + q^3 + q^5 + q^7) (q^2 + q^4 + q^6 + q^8) \nonumber \\ 
    &= q^{1+2} + q^{1+4} + q^{1+6} + q^{1+8} + q^{3+2} + q^{3+4} + q^{3+6} + q^{3+8} \nonumber \\
    &\qquad + q^{5+2} + q^{5+4} + q^{5+6} + q^{5+8} + q^{7+2} + q^{7+4} + q^{7+6} + q^{7+8} \nonumber \\
    &= q^3 + 2q^5 + 3q^7 + 4q^9 + 3q^{11} + 2q^{13} + q^{15}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

About the `\nonumber` method… I have nothing to say, it works, but may be there are other better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three variations on the numbering them, all using `\MoveEqLeft`.  show an unnumbered group of equations, or all numbered but the middle one, or one number for the whole group.

`\MoveEqLeft` is defined in `mathtools` specifically for the case of a long first line in an alignment. I use it in a slighly different context but the global idea  is the same: this command `replaces` the ampersand and move the firstline by 2 em by default; here I suse the optional argument, which is the number of em's by which thhe first line is moved. Actually, it can be applied to any line of an alignment, but I think it can make sense only for the first.

The second idea is to put the second line in a `multlined` environment, also defined in mathtools.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[4] (q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\
&=\begin{multlined}[t]
  q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8}
\end{multlined}\\
&=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{align*}

\begin{align}
\MoveEqLeft[4] (q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\
&=\begin{multlined}[t] \notag
  q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8}
\end{multlined}\\
&=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
\MoveEqLeft[4] (q^1+q^3+q^5+q^7)(q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8) \\
&=\begin{multlined}[t]
  q^{1+2}+q^{1+4}+q^{1+6}+q^{1+8}+q^{3+2}+q^{3+4}+q^{3+6}+q^{3+8}\\+ q^{5+2}+q^{5+4}+q^{5+6}+q^{5+8}+q^{7+2}+q^{7+4}+q^{7+6}+q^{7+8}
\end{multlined}\\
&=q^3+2q^5+3q^7+4q^9+3q^{11}+2q^{13}+q^{15}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}


    \end{document}
```

[image]