# label \theequation inside math

Tags: labels

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        J
        &= J_0 + 2 m r^2 
        & \label{eq:asdf}\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation) 
        && \tilde{J} 
        &= J_0 + 2 m \tilde{r}^2 & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
    \end{align*}
    \eqref{eq:asdf}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: outputOfCode]

I want to reference (1).

Comment: You need to put `\label` after `\refstepcounter` (although using `align*` and then using `\refstepcounter` by hand is pretty odd:-)

Comment: Try running it twice.  The first run writes the aux file, the second reads it.

Comment: May be of interest: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/2417](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/2417)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: equation counter is set to 0 before I call \label. That means that there has to appear a (0). If that were true, I would be happy.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I ran it 10 times.

Comment: The aux file contains only \relax.  \label isn't writing anything.

Comment: @MichaelBanucu the value of the counter is irrelevant what matters is the current referencerable value and that is empty until there has been a refstepcounter. try putting `\section{foo}` before your equation and you will see the `\ref` picks up the section number. The usage above is _exactly_ like putting `\lable` before `\caption` in a figure, about which there are several answers on this site and elsewhere

Comment: @JohnKormylo: \relax is not working or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: ah in addition to coming after refstepcounter you need to undo amsmath's redefintion

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How do I undo amsmath's redefinition? What is amsmath's redefinition? Where can I find out what is amsmaths's redefinition? I think that I have to set the "current label". I think that's what \section and align are doing. But how do I set the current label?

Comment: `\refstepcounter` sets the current label (which is why you need to do that first, as for undoing amsmath definition John beat me by a few seconds:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amsmath sets \let\label=\@gobble in align*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\let\goodlabel=\label
    \begin{align*}
        J
        &= J_0 + 2 m r^2 
        & \refstepcounter{equation}\goodlabel{eq:asdf}(\theequation)
        && \tilde{J} 
        &= J_0 + 2 m \tilde{r}^2 & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
    \end{align*}
    \eqref{eq:asdf}
\end{document}
```

[image: gobble]

Comment: Ohh you beat me by 10 sec:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle - If it makes you feel any better, it took longer than that to crop the image.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: what is \@gobble?

Comment: @Michael Banucu - I've seen it before but never seen the \def.  I've always assumed from context that it eats arguments, but otherwise does nothing (like \relax).