# Cleveref does not sort self defined tags

Tags: cross-referencing, align, cleveref

Because I have many equations in my document and most of them do not need to be referred to, I always use `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`. For the times I do need an equation number I have written a command

```
\newcommand{\nr}{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

This works great, only cleveref does not sort it. An example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\newcommand{\nr}{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  foo \nr\label{eq1}\\
  bar \nr\label{eq2}
\end{align*}

\cref{eq2,eq1}

\end{document}
```

This outputs "eqs. (2) and (1)" instead of "eqs. (1) and (2)". Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

(Not a solution, just a deeper analysis of the problem.)

It appears that the problem is related to the way the `\tag` macro is defined by the `amsmath` package. In the code given below, the equation numbers are sorted correctly if one (i) defines two unnumbered displayed equations via `\[...\]` and (ii) uses `\eqno` (a "primitive" TeX macro) instead of `\tag`. Unfortunately, the `amsmath` package does *not* permit using `\eqno` in its math environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\setlength\textwidth{2in}  % just for this example

\newcommand{\nr}[1]{%  first method uses \tag
     \refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\tag{\theequation}}
\newcommand{\nrx}[1]{% second method uses \eqno
     \refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\eqno(\theequation)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  foo \nr{eq1}\\
  bar \nr{eq2}
\end{align*}
\cref{eq2,eq1}

\[ newfoo \nrx{eq3} \]
\[ newbar \nrx{eq4} \]
\cref{eq4,eq3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your research. Now I have another question: why does `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` instead of `\refstepcounter{equation}` in the second command give me errors?

Comment: @NikkiBisschop - I assume you're getting the error message "Missing number, treated as zero." As a rule, use only `\refstepcounter` to increment a counter if cross-referencing to the numbered item is an objective.

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer, but his seems to work well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% just make sure that cleveref is included last (even after hyperref if used)
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,~and~}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  x &= 1 \nonumber \\
  x &= 2 \nonumber \\
  x &= 3.14159 \label{eq:1}\\
  y &= 4 \label{eq:2}
\end{align}

The first two equations are unnumbered (e.g., working out details) and \cref{eq:2,eq:1} are referenced correctly by cleveref.
Note that by default cleveref will sort the list.
Now, if you want to refer to equation 2 before equation 1 you must be explicit with cleveref, like \cref{eq:2} and \labelcref{eq:1}.
This sorting behavior can be changed globally with the option nosort.

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution_pdf]