# Equation numbering inside align*

Tags: equations, align

Consider:

```
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix} P_1 J&0\\0&NP_2\end{bmatrix}=\\&\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0& P_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\stackrel{2.18}{=}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]\begin{bmatrix}
J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}\\
&\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}[EV,AW]^{-1}EA[V,W]=[EV,AW]^{-1}AE[V,W]\\
&\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\\
&\stackrel{(2.18)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0&P_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}JP_1&0\\0&P_2N\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
```

The last line should produce an automatic equation numbering, say 2.15. I am using `\begin{equation}\end{equation}`, but while I am writing

```
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix} P_1 J&0\\0&NP_2\end{bmatrix}=\\&\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0& P_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\stackrel{2.18}{=}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]\begin{bmatrix}
J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}\\
&\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}[EV,AW]^{-1}EA[V,W]=[EV,AW]^{-1}AE[V,W]\\
&\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{equation}
&\stackrel{(2.18)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0&P_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}JP_1&0\\0&P_2N\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{equation}
\end{align*}
```

it is showing some error.

Comment: You can't nest environments that start math mode like that, use one `align`, and `\nonumber` on the lines that shouldn't be numbered.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726

Comment: I dont understand, could anyone give a code :( :(

Comment: Take your first code, replace `align*` with `align` (i.e. remove the `*`), and then before the `\\ ` of the first few lines, write `\nonumber`.

Comment: If you want automatic numbering of equations, use `align`, not `align*`.

Comment: what do you mean by first few lines

Comment: @Urgent -- all lines that shouldn't be numbered

Comment: It seems strange to me to put equation numbers above the equals signs. Why not just put them at the end of the line, as normal? When you write `\begin{align}A&=B\\ &=C\end{align}` the first equation number already refers to `A=B` and the second to `B=C`. I can see the point if you're saving space by putting multiple equalities on one line but, with one per line, it just looks weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `aligned` inside `equation`, so you can choose what line the global equation number will be aligned with; in this case, with `\begin{aligned}[b]`, we have the last line.

You shouldn't hardwire the numbers, but use `\eqref` together with suitable `\label` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}\setcounter{equation}{9}
\begin{equation} \label{a}
0=0
\end{equation}
\setcounter{equation}{17}
\begin{equation} \label{b}
1=1
\end{equation}

This was just to set up numbers to be used in the main
display
\begin{equation} \label{c}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\begin{bmatrix} P_1 J&0\\0&NP_2\end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0& P_2\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]
&\qquad\overset{\eqref{b}}{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]
&\qquad\overset{\eqref{a}}{=}
  [EV,AW]^{-1}EA[V,W]=[EV,AW]^{-1}AE[V,W]
\\[1ex]
&\qquad\overset{\eqref{a}}{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}[V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]
&\qquad\overset{\eqref{b}}{=}
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0&P_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}JP_1&0\\0&P_2N\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, here's a solution that uses a single `align` environment, rather than an `aligned` environment nested inside an `equation` environment. The cost is that the first four rows -- the ones that aren't supposed to be numbered -- need to be terminated with a `\nonumber` (or `\notag`) directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}P_1 J&0\\0&NP_2\end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0&P_2\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
&\quad\stackrel{(2.18)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix} 
  [V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]
  \begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
&\quad\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}[EV,AW]^{-1}EA[V,W]
  =[EV,AW]^{-1}AE[V,W]\nonumber\\
&\quad\stackrel{(2.10)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
  [V,W]^{-1}[EV,AW]
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}\nonumber\\
&\quad\stackrel{(2.18)}{=}\begin{bmatrix}J&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}P_1&0\\0&P_2\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&N\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}JP_1&0\\0&P_2N\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```