# How use "align" but with numeration of just some equation?

Tags: align, enumerate

How use "align" but with numeration of just some equation ? For example,

```
\begin{align}

f(x)&=P(x)\\

&= Q(x)\\

&=R(x)

\end{align}
```

will numerate all equation. How can I do if I want to numerate only the second equation for example ? I tried

```
\begin{align*}

f(x)&=P(x)\\

&= Q(x)\tag{2}\\

&=R(x)

\end{align*}
```

but I would like to numerote it in a coherent way with previous numerotation, i.e. if the previous equation is numeroted with (6) I want to give automatically the number (7). Is it possible ?

Comment: What about of `\nonumber` in the same line of the equation that should not be numbered ;-)

Comment: Remember: Blank lines are not allowed in the environments of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- with `amsmath`, `\notag` is equivalent to `\nonumber`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: But the O.P. does not use `\notag` neither ;-) And I think it is a clear duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `align` or similar environments, `\nonumber` suppresses numbering of the given line.  You only need `\tag` if you need special labelling.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  f(x)&=P(x) \nonumber \\
      &=Q(x) \label{eq:2} \\
      &=R(x) \nonumber \\
      &=S(x) \tag{S}\label{eq:S} \\
      &=T(x) \nonumber
\end{align}

Refer to \eqref{eq:2} and \eqref{eq:S}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for. (+1) and thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=P(x)\\
&= Q(x)\\
&=R(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

The equation number is vertically centred by default. You can have it at the top or at the bottom with the options `[t]` or `[b]`.

Comment: I think the OP wants this _without_ the `\tag{2}` so gets the automatic number

Comment: Yes, @DavidCarlisle is right. I don't want to have \tag{2} to have a coherent number with previous numerotations.

Comment: I tried it work (except replace \tag by \label

Comment: @Surb: Yes, I copied your code to start with, and forgot to remove `\tag{2}`. I've fixed it.

Comment: But we agree that I must add \label{xx} at the second line, no ? (since you erased it). Because by writting \label{xx} at the second line, I indeed have a correct number, and by putting exactly the code you wrote, noting appear.

Comment: @Surb not the number is for the entire equation, so you can put `\label` anywhere, eg just after `\begin{equation}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see. But what I would like is to give a number only on specific equation, not all of them (for example just the second or the third). Is there such a possibility ?

Comment: @Surb this is for a single number (from `equation`) if you really want to number the individual lines go back to using `align` as in your original and use `\nonumber` on rows not to be numbered, as it was mentioned previously in comments. However not numbering f(x)=P(x) but numbering =Q(x) would look pretty strange.

Comment: @Surb: You also have the possibility to nest all this in the `subequations` environment which will number lines as `(7a)`, `(7b)`, &c., with always the possibility to use `\nonumber` (or `\notag`) for specific lines.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose the path of Andrew swann, but instead of removing numbers in `align` I would add numbers to `align*` this has already been shown, and here I cite the answer from [align* but show one equation number at the end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42726/align-but-show-one-equation-number-at-the-end) :

> Use `\tag`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a &=b \\
    &=c \numberthis \label{eqn}
\end{align*}
Equation \eqref{eqn} shows that $a=c$.
\begin{equation}
    d = e
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> See page 3 of the amsmath package >documentation for details.

This answer was given by Ian Thompson