# Numbering a table at the right side

Tags: tables, align

I have a table which looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[!hbt] 
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{r r c l r}
     Min & $\mathbf{c}^\intercal\mathbf{x}$ & \\
     subject to & $A\mathbf{x}$ & $=$& $\mathbf{b}$ \\
     & $\mathbf{x}$ & $\geqslant$ & 0.
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I want to give this table a number, just like an equation or an alignment would have. Is this possible? And if so, how can I acomplish this?

Comment: You should give it a caption instead, that is the traditional way of numbering a table, especially a floating table like this one.

Comment: If you want to use the equation counter, put it in an `euation` environment. What's inside the `tabular` environment will be in text mode.

Comment: @daleif I used the table environment to align my equations in a certain way. I do not use any lines, so It does not really look like a table. So a caption is not what I want.

Comment: @Bernard This works. Only the horizontal spacing is increasing now...

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘the horizontal spacing’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a table is not the right tool for what you are trying to achieve. (Also, the `table` environment does nothing in your example.) Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve, `align`, `align*` or `aligned` may be the best choice for you. I have included some examples below.

Some general notes: One of the strengths of LaTeX is being able to separate the typography from the source input. While this is only true to a certain degree when it comes to maths, I would recommend always defining macros that represent what you want to express semantically (e.g. `\vec` for vectors) and define their behavior in the preamble (e.g. "print this symbol in a bold font"). When you are not happy with how some of the symbols are predefined (e.g. you prefer `\geqslant` or you want multiplication (`\times`) to be typeset using a centered dot rather than a cross), just change them and keep using the macro in a *semantically* consistent way.

<sup>`\numberthis` taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42728/48973).</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand*\vec[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand*\transpose[1]{{{#1}^\intercal}}
\let\geq\geqslant

\newcommand*\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \llap{\text{Min}\qquad}
        \transpose{\vec c} \vec x   \\
        \llap{\text{subject to}\qquad}
        A \vec x &= \vec b  \\
        \vec x &\geq 0
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
    \text{Min}&&
    \transpose{\vec c} \vec x   &&\\
    \text{subject to}&&
    A \vec x &= \vec b  \\&&
    \vec x &\geq 0
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
    \text{Min}&&
    \transpose{\vec c} \vec x   &&\\
    \text{subject to}&&
    A \vec x &= \vec b  \\&&
    \vec x &\geq 0 \numberthis
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]